# How properly terminate a process in Windows batch file or PowerShell performed by Azure DevOps?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure DevOps deployment, I need to stop an existing console app launched in background by my task scheduler to deploy the new version. How can I kill or terminate properly the running app before copying the new version?

[image: Cmd.exe exited with code '128'.]

I do a `START /wait taskkill /f /im "WorkflowMonitor.exe"` in the script of my `Kill Workflow exe` step.

Comment: WorkflowMonitor.exe is based on an infinite loop in C#. I also need to check the application is running when I kill. I can have an error when I kill a process that is running. I can also have an error when I kill a process that is NOT running. In fact, I need a trykill command.

Comment: You can use `tasklist.exe` to determine whether the executable is running first. ```%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /Fi "Status Eq Running" /Fi "ImageName Eq WorkflowMonitor.exe" 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "WorkflowMonitor.exe" 1>NUL && (%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /Im "WorkflowMonitor.exe" /T 1>NUL 2>&1 & %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak 1>NUL)```.

Answer (score 0):

To kill the task only if it exist:

```
tasklist | findstr /i "WorkflowMonitor.exe" && taskkill /f /im WorkflowMonitor.exe
```

But better to also stop the task with

```
schtasks /end /tn Folder\WorkflowMonitorLauncher
```

Combined it seems to me logic to stop the task first then to kill the process if still active:

```
schtasks /end /tn Folder\WorkflowMonitorLauncher
tasklist | findstr /i "WorkflowMonitor.exe" && taskkill /f /im WorkflowMonitor.exe
```